# How to overwrite data in json?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

*I have React Component:*

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles/editIntern.sass";

const EditIntern = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [name, inputName] = useState("");
  const [email, inputEmail] = useState("");
  const [start, inputStart] = useState("");
  const [end, inputEnd] = useState("");

  const [errorNameEmpty, isErrorNameEmpty] = useState(false);
  const [errorEmailValid, iserrorEmailValid] = useState(false);
  const [errorStartEmpty, isErrorStartEmpty] = useState(false);
  const [errorEndEmpty, isErrorEndEmpty] = useState(false);
  const [errorDate, isErrorDate] = useState(false);

  const validEmail = new RegExp(/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/);

  const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let startDate = new Date(start).getTime();
    let endDate = new Date(end).getTime();

    if (startDate > endDate || startDate === endDate) {
      isErrorDate(true);
    } else {
      isErrorDate(false);
    }

    if (name === "") {
      isErrorNameEmpty(true);
    } else {
      isErrorNameEmpty(false);
    }

    if (email === "") {
      iserrorEmailValid(true);
    } else if (!validEmail.test(email)) {
      iserrorEmailValid(true);
    } else {
      iserrorEmailValid(false);
    }

    if (start === "") {
      isErrorStartEmpty(true);
    } else {
      isErrorStartEmpty(false);
    }

    if (end === "") {
      isErrorEndEmpty(true);
    } else {
      isErrorEndEmpty(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchIntern = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/interns/${id}`);
      const intern = await response.json();
      console.log(intern);
      inputName(intern.name);
      inputEmail(intern.email);
      inputStart(intern.internshipStart.slice(0, 10));
      inputEnd(intern.internshipEnd.slice(0, 10));
    };
    fetchIntern();
    console.log(`I want to get intern with id: ${id}!`);
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <img className="Logo" src="../logo.svg" alt="logo" />
      <section className="EditIntern">
        <NavLink to="/">
          <button className="EditIntern_back">
            <img
              className="EditIntern_back-img"
              src="../button_back_icon.svg"
              alt="button_back"
            />{" "}
            Back to list
          </button>
        </NavLink>
        <form className="EditIntern_form">
          <h4 className="EditIntern_form-title">Edit</h4>
          <label className="EditIntern_form-label EditIntern_form-label_name">
            Full name *
          </label>
          <input
            className={
              errorNameEmpty
                ? "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_name  EditIntern_form-input--error"
                : "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_name"
            }
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => {
              inputName(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          {errorNameEmpty ? (
            <>
              <img
                className="EditIntern_form-error_name--icon"
                src="../error_icon.svg"
                alt="error"
              />
              <span className="EditIntern_form-error EditIntern_form-error_name">
                Name can't be empty
              </span>
            </>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}

          <label className="EditIntern_form-label EditIntern_form-label_email">
            Email address *
          </label>
          <input
            className={
              errorNameEmpty
                ? "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_email EditIntern_form-input--error"
                : "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_email"
            }
            type="text"
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => {
              inputEmail(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          {errorEmailValid ? (
            <>
              <img
                className="EditIntern_form-error_email--icon"
                src="../error_icon.svg"
                alt="error"
              />
              <span className="EditIntern_form-error EditIntern_form-error_email">
                Example: email@gmail.com
              </span>
            </>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}

          <label className="EditIntern_form-label EditIntern_form-label_start">
            Internship start *
          </label>
          <input
            className={
              errorNameEmpty
                ? "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_start EditIntern_form-input--error"
                : "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_start"
            }
            type="date"
            name="email"
            value={start}
            onChange={(e) => {
              inputStart(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          {errorStartEmpty ? (
            <>
              <img
                className="EditIntern_form-error_start--icon"
                src="../error_icon.svg"
                alt="error"
              />
              <span className="EditIntern_form-error EditIntern_form-error_start">
                Start date can't be empty
              </span>
            </>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}

          <label className="EditIntern_form-label EditIntern_form-label_end">
            Internship end *
          </label>
          <input
            className={
              errorNameEmpty
                ? "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_end EditIntern_form-input--error"
                : "EditIntern_form-input EditIntern_form-input_end"
            }
            type="date"
            name="email"
            value={end}
            onChange={(e) => {
              inputEnd(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          {errorEndEmpty ? (
            <>
              <img
                className="EditIntern_form-error_end--icon"
                src="../error_icon.svg"
                alt="error"
              />
              <span className="EditIntern_form-error EditIntern_form-error_end">
                End date can't be empty
              </span>
            </>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
          {errorDate ? (
            <>
              <img
                className="EditIntern_form-error_start--icon"
                src="../error_icon.svg"
                alt="error"
              />
              <img
                className="EditIntern_form-error_end--icon"
                src="../error_icon.svg"
                alt="error"
              />
              <span className="EditIntern_form-error EditIntern_form-error_date">
                Start date more or equal to end date
              </span>
            </>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}

          <input
            className="EditIntern_form-submit"
            type="submit"
            value="Submit"
            onClick={onFormSubmit}
          />
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditIntern;
```

**The task is to update the data about the intern in which we are currently located (to understand this, the component has a unique id with which we view the specific intern we need).
After filling out the form and clicking on the Submit button, the data about the intern should be overwritten.
All interns are stored in the local db.json file:**

```
{
    "interns": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bird Ramsey",
            "email": "birdramsey@nimon.com",
            "internshipStart": "2021-07-01T00:00+00Z",
            "internshipEnd": "2021-09-30T00:00+00Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Lillian Burgess",
            "email": "lillianburgess@luxuria.com",
            "internshipStart": "2021-07-01T00:00+00Z",
            "internshipEnd": "2021-09-30T00:00+00Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Kristie Cole",
            "email": "kristiecole@quadeebo.com",
            "internshipStart": "2020-07-01T00:00+00Z",
            "internshipEnd": "2020-09-30T00:00+00Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Leonor Cross",
            "email": "leonorcross@gronk.com",
            "internshipStart": "2020-07-01T00:00+00Z",
            "internshipEnd": "2020-09-30T00:00+00Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Marsh Mccall",
            "email": "marshmccall@ultrimax.com",
            "internshipStart": "2020-07-01T00:00+00Z",
            "internshipEnd": "2020-09-30T00:00+00Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

**I have never encountered the task of overwriting information in a json file, maybe someone will tell you how to do this?**

Comment: if i understand your question correctly, once you have found the object `id` while running a loop over `interns` , you could simply overwrite like this `intern[i].name = newName` `intern[i].email = newEmail` and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Firstly, the component that I showed specifically contains the desired intern and its data. Secondly, does your way overwrite my json file?

Comment: There are two ways you can overwrite your JSON object . 1. If you already have another JSON object which you want to replace with the old JSON object , for example. 
`Json_1 = { interns: [{name: "old intern"}]}` and `json_2 = {interns: [{name: "new intern"}]}`
then you could just simply assign `json_1 = json_2` and that would overwrite `json_1` object.

2. Secondly, if you don't want to overwrite whole json array, and only want one to mutate one object, you would iterate over the `interns` array, find the id, and replace keys with new values as i suggested in my first comment.